# Is the "sum" of a "symmetric" set of vectors always $0$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

**Edit:** This is a very silly question in retrospect, and I don't think that I asked the question that I meant to, but the answers provided *are* correct, so the question stays.

---

Let $V$ be a set of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ such that for each $\mathbf v\in V$, there exists $\mathbf v'\in V$ such that $\mathbf v+\mathbf v'=\mathbf 0$. Choose a set $U\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ and a function $\varphi:U\to V$ such that $\varphi$ is bijective and the integral...

$$\int_U\varphi(\mathbf u)\ d^m\mathbf u$$

...is defined. Is it the case that...

$$\int_U\ \varphi(\mathbf u)\ d^m\mathbf u=\mathbf 0?$$

**Note:** the integral of the "parameterization" $\varphi$ is used in place of $\int_V \mathbf vd^n\mathbf v$ just in case $V$ is "sufficiently horrible." The idea is that we can always choose a "nice" set $U$ so that the integral makes sense regardless of what $V$ is. I don't know if it's necessary to make this explicit, but I'd like to avoid any ambiguity.

---

I have no idea where to begin with this. It holds in such an obvious way for every conceivable example that I'm struggling to formulate any kind of rigorous explanation. And since I take for granted it's entirely possible that, through some astonishing feat of $17$-dimensional fractal wizardry, my assumption is entirely wrong.

My intuition says "partition $U$ into 'positive' and 'negative' subsets, then the integral of either is the opposite of the other and their sum is the integral of the whole," but the word "partition" makes me think about set theory and non-measurable sets and that time I was attacked by a measure theorist for trying a similar trick and the more that I think about it the more I realize that I'm not qualified to address the general case (where $V$ is arbitrary.) Like, if you told me...

> "It is consistent with ZFC that there exists a set $V$ such that for every choice of $U$ and $\varphi$ such that the above integral is defined, if $P$ is a partition of $U$ into exactly two subsets such that for at least one $U'\in P$ the restriction of the above integral to $U'$ is defined, then there exists a set $U^*\in P$ such that the above integral restricted to $U^*$ is not defined."

...I would probably believe you.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, this is very much false, even when $m=n=1$. For example, take $V=[-1,1]$ and $\phi$ just about any nonlinear bijection, say $U=[\frac1e,e]$ and $\phi(x)=\log x$. Integrals don't just sum all points with equal weights—the exact functions involved determine how much each point is weighted.

Comment: To give the simplest possible example I can think of take $f:[-\frac{1}{2},1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ defined by, for $x<0$, $f(x)=2x$ and for $x\geq0$, $f(x)=x$. With integral $\frac{1}{4}\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example.

In $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$, let $U$ and $V$ be the unit disk $\{z : |z|\le 1\} = \{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$.  Certainly it is "symmetric" in the sense mentioned.  But how about
$\varphi : U \to V$ given by a Möbius transformation
$$
\varphi(z) = \frac{2z+1}{z+2}
$$
It maps the unit disk $U$ onto the unit disk $V$, but $f(0)=1/2$.

We can compute
$$
\varphi(x+i y) = {\frac {2\,{x}^{2}+2\,{y}^{2}+5\,x+2}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+4\,x+4}} + i\,{\frac {3y}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+4\,x+4}}
\\
\varphi(re^{i\theta})=
{\frac {2+5\,r\cos \left( \theta \right) +2\,{r}^{2}}{4+4\,r\cos
 \left( \theta \right) +{r}^{2}}}
+i {\frac {3r\sin \left( \theta \right) }{4+4\,r\cos \left( \theta
 \right) +{r}^{2}}}
$$
and then
$$
\iint_U \varphi(x+iy)\;dx\;dy =
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}\varphi(re^{i\theta})\;r\;dr\;d\theta =
 \pi \ne 0
$$