# Is every "symmetric," and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ with finitely many connected components Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We assume the Euclidean topology, metric, and norm on $\Bbb R^n$ throughout. As such, we will not distinguish between vectors and points in $\Bbb R^n$ (a point and its position vector are regarded as the same object.)

---

Call a set $U\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ "symmetric" if and only if for every $\mathbf u\in U$, there exists $\mathbf u'\in U$ such that $\mathbf u+\mathbf u'=\mathbf 0$.

Call a set $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ bounded if and only if there exists a real number $r>0$ such that $\Vert\mathbf u\Vert\le r$ for each $\mathbf u\in U$ (this is equivalent to other definitions of boundedness.)

Let $V$ be a symmetric and bounded set having finitely many connected components.

1. Is $V$ Lebesgue measurable?
2. Is it the case that...

$$\int_V\mathbf v\ d\lambda^n(\mathbf v)=\mathbf 0$$

...where $\lambda^n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$?

---

While these are technically two separate questions, a positive answer to the second implies a positive answer to the first, and *any* answer to the second requires an answer to the first. As such, I am asking them together.

I have never taken measure theory, but it is my understanding that the Riemann integrals...

$$\int_V\mathbf v\ d^n\mathbf v,\qquad\int_Vd^n\mathbf v$$

...are defined only if $V$ is Lebesgue measurable, in which case...

$$\int_V\mathbf v\ d^n\mathbf v=\int_V\mathbf v\ d\lambda^n(\mathbf v)$$

...and...

$$\int_Vd^n\mathbf v=\int_Vd\lambda^n(\mathbf v)=\lambda^n(V)$$

Thus, the question of whether or not...

$$\int_V\mathbf v\ d^n\mathbf v=\mathbf 0$$

...for every suitable $V$ - which was the question I *intended* (and failed) to ask [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506138/is-the-sum-of-a-symmetric-set-of-vectors-always-0) - boils down to whether or not $V$ is "Riemann measurable." Since I do not know 1) if there is a measure $\mu$ such that Riemann integration over $V$ is defined iff $V$ is measurable and...

$$\int_V d^n\mathbf v=\mu(V)$$

...for all measurable $V$ 2) enough about measure theory to know whether or not $V$ is measurable given such $\mu$ - I have decided to pose the problem for the case of the Lebesgue integral, instead. Hopefully someone who understands Lebesgue integration will be able to answer this question, and I can work back to the original problem from there.

---

**Remark:** If $V$ is a symmetric, bounded region, homeomorphic to an $n$-ball, with a piecewise smooth boundary (that is, there exist [finitely many] differentiable functions $\mathbf f_1,\ldots,\mathbf f_k:[0,1]^m\to\Bbb R^n$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k \mathbf f_i([0,1]^m)=\partial V$), then $V$ is Lebesgue measurable and the identity...

$$\int_V\mathbf v\ d^n\mathbf v=0$$

...(using Riemann integration) holds. This is the trivial case for the problem. Part of the motivation for this question is addressing the case where $V$ has arbitrarily many - perhaps infinitely many - holes and/or $\partial V$ is not piecewise-smooth. For example, $V$ could be a Menger sponge, or $\partial V$ could be a union of romanesco broccolis (as you can see, I also know nothing about fractals.)

Comment: The standard term for "chunky" is having finitely many connected components.

Comment: @EricWofsey Good to know. Will correct.

Comment: If $V$ is Lebesgue measurable, then (2) is indeed true by the change-of-variables theorem (since the map $\sigma(v)=-v$, which has unit determinant, $\sigma(V)=V$, and introduces a minus sign in the integrand... so it's the analogue of the fact that the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval is zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, such a set does not have to be measurable.  For instance, let $X\subset[0,1]$ be any nonmeasurable subset, let $Y=X\times [0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $V=Y\cup-Y\cup([-1,1]\times\{0\})$.  Then $V$ is connected because of the $[-1,1]\cup\{0\}$ term.  If $Y$ were measurable, then $Y\cap(\mathbb{R}\times(0,1))=X\times(0,1)$ would be measurable and thus $X$ would be measurable (since Lebesgue measure on sets $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ coincides with 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the sets $A\times(0,1)$), so $Y$ is not measurable.

Comment: I trust that this is correct, but I feel like it shouldn't work. Break $X$ into $X_I$ and $X_D$, where $X_I$ contains any intervals in $X$ and $X_D$ is whatever's left. Clearly $X_I$ is (1D) measurable (it is the union of countably many disjoint intervals), and $X_I\times[0,1]$ should have the same (2D) measure as $X_I$. Then, since $X_D$ is disconnected, $X_D\times[0,1]$ will be 1-dimensional, so it will have a (2D) measure of $0$. $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$ is also 1-dimensional and adding it to $X_D$ still leaves a 1-dimensional set, so the (2D) measure of $V$ should be $2\lambda(X_I)$.

Comment: Your intuition seems to be going astray when you assume that since $X_D$ doesn't contain any intervals it has to have measure $0$.  This isn't true; for instance, consider the irrationals.  And weirder things can happen; look up "fat Cantor sets".